# Simplex equations using LaTeX

Tags: coding

I am completely new to LaTeX. Can anybody help me in showing how to write simplex equations using LaTeX. ie `z= 3x(1) +5x(2)` and `x(1)<=4` etc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome. // Looks like you can do that with so called math mode. See Ch. 4 here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX . // If possible, please be a bit more specific about what you want to know. This community works best when you can provide Latex code which illustrates your question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
z   &=   3x_1+5x_2 \\
x_1 &\le 4
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```